# How to perform a swipe action in swtableviewcell with out moving the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app i am using swtableviewcell library, it is working fine, when i am performing the swipe action, the cell is moving away and the buttons are appearing, but i want to show the user the image present in the cell, the behaviour i want to achieve is while performing the swipe only move the text and make the buttons appear , the image view is constant, using swtableviewcell by detecting the kcellstate, i am some how achieving that by moving the  image from the left to right while the swipe is being performed, but the animation is not good,the user can see the image being moved, while performing swipe, is there a way to move only text using swtableviewcell or any other.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, while adding the image  to the custom cell, instead of

```
[self.contentView addSubView:itemImage];
```

if i use

```
[self addSubview:itemImage];
```

then the image is added on top of content view and while swiping the item only the content view moves but not the image